# bash is acting up after "rm .bashrc*"

Tags: bash

So I am still fairly new to all of this, that is coding, OS X Snow Leopard, bash and the likes. I wanted to configure my prompt to display the current working directory. Knowing about Google I searched the web and tried a few linux bash tutorials that suggested configuring a `.bashrc` file, which I did and it didn't work. More googling got me to using a `.profile` file, which did the trick.

So wanting to keep my OS tidy I applied more of my new bash knowledge and went

```
rm .bashrc*
```

to delete the files I created. I must have been a little too thorough though, because I seem to have deleted more than I should have. When I fire up the shell now, I get a bunch of errors:

```
-bash: alias: dev: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: cd Downloads/Dropbox/__dev/: not found
-bash: alias: sample_app: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: cd dev/rails_projects/sample_app/: not found
```

The contents of my .profile is:

```
export PS1="\w>"

alias dev = 'cd Downloads/Dropbox/__dev/'
alias sample_app  = 'cd dev/rails_projects/sample_app/'
```

Any idea what I can do?!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have spaces before and after the equality sign. This should work:

```
export PS1="\w>"

alias dev='cd Downloads/Dropbox/__dev/'
alias sample_app='cd dev/rails_projects/sample_app/'
```